# NotifyDataSetChanged does not update my ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

NotifyDataSetChanged() does not update my ListView even though I'm rereading the serialized xml file. It only updates after oncreate is called again. Reading up on some Java code, it told me to repopulate my listadapter but that still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {

                View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Card, null);

                listView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.cardListView);

                return view;
            }


            public override void OnResume()
            {
                base.OnResume();
                List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
                string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/Gate";
                var cardPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "card.xml");

                if (File.Exists(cardPath))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Card>));
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cardPath);
                    cardList = (List<Card>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    cardList = new List<Card>();
                }

                foreach (Card card in cardList)
                {
                    nameList.Add(card.name);
                }

                var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, nameList);

                listView.Adapter = adapter;

                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Comment: You mean the listview is empty? Are you sure nameList has items?

Comment: Could you first tell what all is happening? What kind of scenario? What is the user doing? Is the xml file different a 'next' time?

Comment: There is an activity that adds cards which writes the xml file. Then when I resume this fragment it should reread the xml file and update the list with new cards But right now all it it does not update the list unless oncreate() is called again.

Answer (score 2):

You should only create the adapter once, in the OnCreate, and store it.

Then, in the OnResume(), only update the values by using adapter.AddAll(nameList) and call NotifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Very different from native version, I've been fighting against this issue for few minutes and you pointed the most reliable way.